# How does IFTTT manage identities?

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-provider

It seems to me like IFTTT (ifttt.com) allows you to create a master account, and then assign to that account permissions to a great deal of cloud services.

How is it doing this? Is it using OpenID Connect? Is there an open source identity management package it utilizes?

This doesn't feel like SAML to me. I don't see the crazy tokens, and it works with websites that for SAML need some configuration.

This feels more like an OAUTH2 library of some kind that manages and stores tokens and issues refresh tokens to call REST APis and perform actions based on "recipes".

Can anyone shed some light here?